# WordPress > Error when pasting link into Facebook

Tags: facebook

When you paste a link into your Facebook status bar, you normally get a preview of the site.

When I paste my WordPress site in, I get `WordPress > Error`.

**Screenshot**:   http://cl.ly/2L160u1Y253V1Y251a1Q

**Site:** http://www.andrewjamesobrien.com/

I thought it might be a theme-level issue, but even when I enable TwentyEleven, I get the same result.

Anyone run into this before?

Thanks

Terry

Comment: I get an error too when viewing that site

Answer (score 1):

Sure you tested with twentyeleven?

Try reuploading `wp-admin` and `wp-includes`

Your current theme code is messy with a missing `<html>` tag and other errors and that *might* be causing the strange link error:
[[Invalid] Markup Validation of   andrewjamesobrien.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.andrewjamesobrien.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.